# Export imageCollection to asset

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

Is it possible to export a collection of images directly to the asset by renaming the images? I have tried to use fito's geetbox but I can't do it.

My code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var img = ee.Image(listOfImage.get(i));
    var id = img.id().getInfo() || 'image_'+i.toString();
    var region = opt.region || img.geometry().bounds().getInfo()["system:Index"];
    var assetId = SCI_ENERO
    
    Export.image.toAsset({
      image: img,
      description: id,
      assetId: assetId,
      region: region,
      scale: opt.scale,
      maxPixels: opt.maxPixels})
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know that guy, but I think you have taken his code and tried to implemented directly, but you didn't adapt it to your needs.

You have two ways

To adapt it:

```
var p = ee.Geometry.Point([-72, -42])
var col = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
            .filterBounds(p)
            .limit(5)

var size = col.size().getInfo()
var listOfImage = col.toList(size)

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var img = ee.Image(listOfImage.get(i));
    var id = img.id().getInfo() || 'image_'+i.toString();
    var region = p.buffer(1000)
    var assetId = 'TEST'
    
    Export.image.toAsset({
      image: img,
      description: id,
      assetId: assetId,
      region: region,
      scale: 10,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
  }
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5d3a58b8d035d9bb29014dcf91a2a162

Or just use his (awesome) package:

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

var p = ee.Geometry.Point([-72, -42])
var col = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
            .filterBounds(p)
            .limit(5)

var asset = 'TEST'
var options = {
  name: 'S2_{system_date}',
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  region: p.buffer(1000)
}

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toAsset(col, asset, options)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/387777af874beed8a63bd6b4cff8bfa8